# Versioning of data handling pipeline elements

Tags: design-patterns, algorithms, python

I have developed a custom-made Python package, which provides 2 classes to play with: Stage and Step. They operate based on a **Chain of Responsibility** design pattern, and behave in a way where:

- Both Stage and Step possess handle(request) method
- Stage has a list of Stages or Steps underneath it
- Step is the endpoint, which contains logic to be executed on the incoming request

In case of Stage, executing its handle(request) method will make it iterate over children elements in its list, and execute their handle(request) method while passing **request** argument in-between them (updated with each element it passes through).

In case of a Step, I have an abstract method logic(request), which needs to be overwritten by the user when inheriting from this class, in order to introduce some logic it needs to apply to incoming request argument.

[image: Pipeline logic]

As a bit of a background to actual application:
This pipeline will be used for data processing in an ML project, where a Flask server with REST API receives a request with data in JSON format, then processes this data by merging all different data sources in that request, adds new derived entries to it, and then spits it out on the other end ready to be fed into a ML model created in sci-kit learn.

Steps will be set in stone for each release. However, information about version of pipeline each case's data has been pushed through before ML prediction will be kept on the record as well, in a DB managed by another module coded in Django. In case a newer pipeline is available, internal logic of the Django module would prompt a redo of the data parsing through that new pipeline, followed by a new prediction via this ML model.

Now, I would like to introduce some sort of version control mechanism inside of this pipeline, so that pipeline can identify itself with some unique marker, unique to the set of **version and list of steps** included in it. I need it, so that if let's say I introduce some new steps into the pipeline in the future, I would like to be able to e.g. redo so older requests, which have been done with an older version of the pipeline.

I have been wondering about what sort of mechanisms I could leverage to get this done, but so far my only idea was to tag each step & stage with version attribute, like self._version = "1.0", plus have the running script actually count number of steps+stages inside of the pipeline from Stage 0's perspective, and somehow combine it with versions sum. While simple, this would require me to remember to up-rev version attribute on each step I would rework  etc., and would be prone for an error.

Another idea I came upon, was for a mechanism which would physically read class files each stage/step are instantiated from, and compile some sort of numeric representation of all characters in the file, which could be summed up and represented at the Stage 0 piece as a version of the pipeline. Dunno, if that is worth consideration though, since it is a blunt-approach to the problem.

I was wondering, if there are any alternative methods of doing something like this?

Comment: I guess there must be some code which actually assembles the pipeline. That code is probably what you need to version, nothing else (if I got this right).

Comment: To answer your questions: (1) This pipeline will be used for data processing in an ML project, where a Flask server with REST API receives a request with data in JSON format, then processes this data by merging all different data sources in that request, adds new derived entries to it, and then spits it out on the other end ready to be fed into a ML model created in sci-kit learn.

Comment: (2) Steps will be set in stone for each release. However, information about version of pipeline data has been pushed through before ML prediction will be kept on the record as well, in a DB managed by another module coded in Django. In case a newer pipeline is available, internal logic of the Django module would prompt a redo of the data parsing through that new pipeline, followed by a new prediction via this ML model.

Comment: I still wonder where the code "lives" which assembles the pipeline. Is there a function or class `PipelineBuilder` which creates the specific stages and steps, and puts the lists together? Or does each `Stage` object this on its own?

Comment: My implementation of Stage class makes use of os.walk(".") function to search top-to-bottom from its root folder for .py files which feature names complying with a given regex pattern. All identified files are then imported as modules, and classes from them are instantiated and placed in that Stage class' list. This approach allowed me to effectively create a top_lvl folder, drop in it a .py file with Stage0 class inheriting from Stage, and then create sub-folders with Stage1, Stage2 (and 2.1&2.2 under it), which in turn pull in Step-inheriting classes with specific regex in their names.

Comment: This allows me to just import Stage0 class into the runner script located elsewhere in the app, and allow it to do the heavy-lifting for me.

Comment: So the Stages/Steps tree is defined by what source code file is placed where in a folder structure? That sounds like it prevents any reusage of Stages and Steps at different locations in the tree, it sounds like the order of steps or sub-stages in a Stage isn't well defined (or entangled with the file names?), and it sounds like it makes providing different tree versions (with reusage of steps/stages across tress) in parallel hard. Wouldn't an explicit tree building code avoid all those issues?

Comment: Yes, folder structure dictates what stages/steps are assigned to a list of a stage above them. On top of that, both Stages and Steps have an Observer pattern built into them, which upon their execution notifies a dictionary in Stage or Step class' class attribute about it having been executed. Order of Stage & Step objects execution is dictated by the requirement for previously completed Stage or Step, which is a class attribute you overwrite in your definition of each class inheriting from Stage or Step.

Comment: This way, each object knows if it can use its handle() method, or wait for a next pass in Stage's handle() loop.

Comment: To answer your suggestion about a builder pattern explicitly assembling the pipeline in code: it would address the issue with versioning, however changes to the pipeline would require the code to be revisited every time an update to order of steps, introduction of new ones or removal of some older ones would be required. I went in the direction of self-managed pipeline assembly to avoid the need to touch setup code every time this needs to happen.

Comment: And when you define the pipeline through a folder structure + class attributes, why does this definition not have to be revisited as well? Honestly, for me it looks the versioning problem arises from a "(maybe too) clever" way of assembling the pipeline. Unfortunately, this approach now paints itself into a corner. This meta information, which steps and stages are in one version of a release, and which order they have, is actually what you need to version. Find a way to make this more explicit, and you have found your solution.

Comment: Would it be acceptable if a change as small as correcting a typo in a comment causes the versioning logic to think a step has a new version? If so, you could calculate a hash over each step file as your version number for that step.

Comment: @DocBrown: I admit, this approach runs itself into the corner due to lack of an explicit building stage. However, due to the nature of its application, I really like the "drag-and-drop" nature of pipeline assembly. When properly marshaled at the remote repo, it allows many contributors to easily add/remove steps in a very fast fashion, and does not involve massive code rewrites - just a new class file being added/removed/amended/moved from a specific spot in the folder structure.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: I have been playing with a similar idea yesterday - I wrote a Mixin class for both Stage and Step, which on initialization finds the location of a file class inheriting after stage/step, and then sums up int values of characters in the file. "Stage" on top of that, during their initialization, query their collections of sub-stages/steps, and sum up all char_sums they see below them, so that eventually Stage0 element seems total sum.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: ... continued: This approach even accounts for order changes in the pipeline (since classes with requirements have their requirements changed in class definition). However, the number seen at the Stage0 level is arbitrary, like 45687, which does not easily translate into any specific version order (did it come before 22584 or after it?). I have toyed with an idea of a locally held csv file which auto-increments versions if mapping of char_sums-version no. it holds does not have that char_sums yet, but it is not a multi-server-proof solution.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: ... continued: Mapping would have to arrive with request on the input, with the external service hitting the pipeline's REST endpoint remembering to query a DB table where this mapping would live. I am not sure, if this is the best solution I could have in place.

Comment: @Greem666, you are correct that with the hash approach you don't get nicely increasing version numbers. Instead you get something akin to git hashes.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I have a more elegant solution for you, based on my understanding of the problem. Do not hesitate to tell me if I'm off.

- Optionally, you can have your pipelines in a standalone git project. Don't do that if it's too difficult to detangle dependencies, but it may make sense.
- Store the git tag or commit id corresponding to the pipeline version inside requests
- Have each request locally checkout the pipeline repository with the given commit id, inside a temp folder, and run the pipeline import from here

This is basically a lightweight containerisation of your pipeline code. We sometimes used this kind of workflow in our domain.

This seem rather straightforward to implement and would enable pipelines of concurrent versions to run in parallel. Since you would rely on effective git repository pointers you would be able to fully leverage its power and avoid rely on shaky checksum handling (beware of sum collisions with this algorithm !)

This is also easier to debug internally since you'd be able to keep track of what version is what directly in the git repository.

Comment: This is quite an elegant solution **@Arthur Hv**, thank you for that. It is something I might consider as a solution to my problem, since that pipeline (the folder with classes inheriting from Stage & Step classes from the package) will actually sit in a GitLab repo.